# Customize jtsage datebox for jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using [this incredibly awesome jquery mobile oriented datepicker](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) that I would like to customize based on device size. I saw some suggestions pointing towards modifying the `CSS` but I am unable to trap the event that creates the popup dialog that comes up with the calendar.

Is there a `jsfiddle` that I can look and learn from?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples on the page you provided, it appears to be binding to the vmouseclick event. So you should be able to use `click`, `vmousedown`, `vmouseup` depending on your needs.

So if you had HTML like:

```
<label for="mydate">Some Date</label>

<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox"}'>
```

Your JQM Would be like:

```
$("mydate").click(function(){
    // Do something
});
```

I don't see any options of configs to adjust the size of the DateBox upon opening. So you would want to examine the CSS and class settings of the `DIV` when it is created and then add your own CSS to override the CSS they use (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />`), or download the CSS and Edit it.

There is no default jsFiddle for this, yet I moved an example into one for you to play with if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pNQeD/